vimscript function suggest in command-line mode?
At home I have Ubuntu LTS and my gVim command-line mode displays a horizontal list of vimscript functions as you type them after you type :call.
At work we run Windows and gVim, but the same horizontal list of functions does not display; I don't know what it's called and I don't know why the vanilla install on Ubuntu does it and at work the gVim for Windows does not display it.  (Which is juxtaposed to what it should be since I have functions I wrote in my vimrc at work).
I keep thinking maybe it has something to do with the Ctrl-X keyboard shortcut, but it's more likely something you have to enable.

See :help defaults.vim. On a system without vimrc, the defaults will kick in. Once you write a vimrc, you have to :source them yourself.

@downvoter Seems like an okay question to me.

I believe it is the wildmenu.
Simply add the following lines to you vimrc file:
set wildmenu
set wildmode=full

After typing :call  if you hit Tab you see in the line before the command line the list of possible options you have (functions).

